# Most compact URL encoding of JSON data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, url-encoding, url-shortener

Some time ago I saw a website that encoded game replay data into unicode characters so that you could copy-and-paste the address to share it with friends. I basically want to do the same thing -- I've got some data in a JavaScript object and I want to put it into the address bar.

I know I can use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) or something like that, but I want a much more compact format.

Turns out this is a little tricky to Google. Most search results turn up URL shorteners, which is distinctly different. I am *not* trying to store a short URL in my database for later lookup. All the data should be in the URL itself.

What encoding can I use for this? A link or description of the algorithm is fine, but impementations for Node/JavaScript would be even better.

I only need to support the latest version of Chrome stable, so I don't care if older browsers can't handle the unicode. I think I'll put the data in the fragment portion (after `#`) so I only need to support whatever encoding rules apply to that piece. I think just about anything is allowed, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go https://github.com/qntm/base65536 & https://www.npmjs.com/package/base65536

> Base65536 is a binary encoding optimised for UTF-32-encoded text and Twitter. This JavaScript module, base65536, is the first implementation of this encoding.

[It featured on hackernews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10683889) some time ago.

Comment: Aha! That solves half the problem. The other half is how do I serialize my JS object into a buffer? `JSON.stringify`? msgpack?

Comment: Yeah I think so, you need a regular string so you are able to encode, then you decode and JSON.parse it.

Comment: BTW "For transmitting data through Twitter, Base65536 is now considered obsolete; see Base2048."

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of [enapupe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553133/65387):

```
import Msgpack from 'msgpack-lite';
import Base65536 from 'base65536';

export function uniencode(obj) {
    return Base65536.encode(Msgpack.encode(obj));
}

export function unidecode(str) {
    return Msgpack.decode(Base65536.decode(str));
}
```

Usage:

```
let o = {foo:'bar',baz:[1,2,3,4,5],quux:'corge'};
console.log(uniencode(o).length,JSON.stringify(o).length); // 24, 46
```

i.e. `uniencode` is about half the length of `JSON.stringify`, or even less according to Twitter (`.length` doesn't count unicode properly. Twitter counts the above as 15 chars). A better measurement is:

```
function len(str) {
    return [...str].length;
}
```

Which gives 15 and 46 respectively.

Comment: Why do I get this error : `base65536__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9___default.a.encode is not a function`

Comment: @Rapido You've got a problem with your webpack setup my dude. Maybe open a new question?

Comment: Fixed in base65536@3.0.2 https://github.com/qntm/base65536/issues/21